# End to end series in googlecharts

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, series

I want to display a target line (a straight horizontal line) in my stacked column charts using googlecharts.
I'm doing it using series attribute in options tag.

```
series : {
    4 : {
        type : "line",
        color : '#FF0000',
        visibleInLegend : false
    }
}
```

The line is being displayed but it is not displayed from end to end. I want my line to touch the y-axis on both the ends.
I tried changing the `type:line` to `type:steppedArea`. The line is displayed from end to end. But it is hidden behind the bars.

```
series : {
    4 : {
        type : "steppedArea",
        color : '#FF0000',
        visibleInLegend : false,
        areaOpacity : 0
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that if the x-axis value is numeric , then it displays properly. I tried even changing that, but of no use.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crazyCoder1989/8p6z4631/97/) demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set min/max for hAxis chart:

```
 viewWindow: {
    min: 0.5,
    max: 2.5
 }
```

then add two dummy rows to dataTable with proper x-axis values (min/max) and y value set to target line level (0.67 in your example):

```
['Machine', '', {
        role : 'style'
    }, '', {
        role : 'style'
    }, '', {
        role : 'style'
    }, '', {
        role : 'style'
    }, ''],
[0.5, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0.067],
[1.0, 0.05, "#808080", 0.0775, "#C71585", 0.069, "#FFC0CB", 0.05, "Blue", 0.067],
[2.0, 0.05, "Yellow", 0.0775, "Pink", 0.069, "#808080", 0.05, "Green", 0.067],
[2.5, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0.067]
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/60q2f7xw/

---

**Edit:**

To get min/max values from first column use [getColumnRange()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods) method:

```
var min = data.getColumnRange(0).min;
var max = data.getColumnRange(0).max;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But how did you determine min and max value?

Comment: And also in this example, I have mentioned only one target line. But in actual chart, I need to display more than one target line. For suppose I need to show 4 target lines.Do I need to add 4 dummy lines as mentioned in your code?

Comment: No, 2 rows are for x-axes values, the lines refer to columns (4, 5, ...). Check my fiddle updated.

Comment: I don't think min/max is a problem: you get them from your first column ('Machine')

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked. Just a last question. How to make the line dashed.Any idea?

Comment: Use lineDashStyle (see https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines)